# Select all which is not in table

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table in MySQL where all employees are listed. I have another where all employees are listed which have to work on a specific day. And now I want to select all employees which have free (or at least are NOT listed in the work-table).
In this **[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88135/1)** you can see my schema.

A code like `SELECT * FROM pf_mitarbeiter WHERE NOT LISTED AS employeeID IN pf_tagesplan_zuteilungen` would be super awesome. But I take other versions as well too.

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` to join `pf_tagesplan_zuteilungen` on `employeeID` with a condition that there's no rows matching `pf_mitarbeiter`:

```
SELECT t1.*
    FROM pf_mitarbeiter t1
    LEFT JOIN pf_tagesplan_zuteilungen t2 ON t2.employeeID = t1.ID AND t2.date = CURDATE()
    WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: If I put this query `SELECT t1.*
    FROM pf_mitarbeiter t1
    LEFT JOIN pf_tagesplan_zuteilungen t2 ON t2.employeeID = t1.ID
    WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
    AND t2.date = CURDATE()` in the database, it selects nothing.. but it should select all employees, because today, nobody has to work.

Comment: I guess this is because you already have records in `pf_tagesplan_zuteilungen` for all employees for the past days. In this case we need to add another condition on `pf_tagesplan_zuteilungen.date` into the `ON` clause. I've updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from A
where not exists
(
   select 1
   from B
   where a.key = b.key
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to join the two tables.  By doing so, you can select all the rows from the `pf_mitarbeiter` table even though there is no related row in the `pf_tagesplan_zuteilungen` table.

```
SELECT
  S.*
FROM
  pf_mitarbeiter S
  LEFT OUTER JOIN pf_tagesplan_zuteilungen T ON (S.ID = T.employeeID)
WHERE
  T.ID IS NULL
;
```

The `IS NULL` condition restricts the join to only return `pf_mitarbeiter` rows where there is no `pf_tagesplan_zuteilungen` row with a matching employeeId.